# EditText isn't getting clear with CustomKeyboard after press clear button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, custom-keyword

This is my custom keyboard class.In keybord i have one key clear when i click on clear key my register editetext should clear but editetx value has been cleared when i debug but in UI edit text is not updating is showing same old value.

I checked on TextWatcher listener also their value is showing nothing after press clear button when I debug, but still edit text is not getting updated.

```
/**
* When an activity hosts a keyboardView, this class allows several EditText's
* to register for it.
* 
*/
class CustomKeyboard extends KeyboardView {

/** A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard. */
private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
/** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
private Activity mHostActivity;

/** The key (code) handler. */
private OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new    OnKeyboardActionListener() {

    public final static int CodeDelete = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
    public final static int CodeCancel = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
    public final static int CodePrev = 55000;
    public final static int CodeAllLeft = 55001;
    public final static int CodeLeft = 55002;
    public final static int CodeRight = 55003;
    public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
    public final static int CodeNext = 55005;
    public final static int CodeClear = 55006;
    public final static int CodeDZero = 55007;
    public final static int Coderefresh = 55008;
    public final static int Codeswap = 55009;
    public final static int emptyKey = 555555008;

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml
        // file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in
        // primaryCode
        // Get the EditText and its Editable
        View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        if (focusCurrent == null
                || focusCurrent.getClass() != EditText.class)
            return;
        EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
        Editable editable = edittext.getText();
        int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();

        // Apply the key to the edittext
        if (primaryCode == CodeCancel) {
            hideCustomKeyboard();
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeDelete) {
            if (editable != null && start > 0)
                editable.delete(start - 1, start);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeClear) {
            if (editable != null){
                editable.clear();
            }
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeLeft) {
            if (start > 0)
                edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeRight) {
            if (start < edittext.length())
                edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllLeft) {
            edittext.setSelection(0);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllRight) {
            edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
        } else if (primaryCode == CodePrev) {
            View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
            if (focusNew != null)
                focusNew.requestFocus();
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeNext) {
            View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
            if (focusNew != null)
                focusNew.requestFocus();
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeDZero) {
            if (editable != null && start > 0)
                editable.insert(start, "00");
        } else if (primaryCode == Coderefresh) {
            // if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
        }else if (primaryCode == emptyKey) {
            // if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
        } 
        else if (primaryCode == Codeswap) {
            // if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
        } else { // insert character
            editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
        }
        long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

        mHostActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "SwipeDown");
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
};

/**
 * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id
 * <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity, and load the keyboard
 * layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for
 * description). Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a
 * <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom
 * of the activity). Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key
 * codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
 * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the
 * {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
 * 
 * @param host
 *            The hosting activity.
 * @param viewid
 *            The id of the KeyboardView.
 * @param layoutid
 *            The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    super(host, null);
    mHostActivity = host;
    mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview
                                            // balloons
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
    // Hide the standard keyboard initially
    mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}

/** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
    return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

/**
 * Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v.
 */
public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    if (v != null)
        ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

/** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
}

/**
 * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the
 * hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
 * 
 * @param resid
 *            The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom
 *            keyboard.
 */
public void registerEditText(int resid) {
    // Find the EditText 'resid'
    EditText edittext = (EditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
    // Make the custom keyboard appear
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom
        // keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the
        // edit box loses focus
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            else
                hideCustomKeyboard();
        }
    });
    edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom
        // keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus
        // (but that had the keyboard hidden).
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCustomKeyboard(v);
        }
    });
    // Disable standard keyboard hard way
    // NOTE There is also an easy way:
    // 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a
    // cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
    edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
            int inType = edittext.getInputType(); // Backup the input type
            edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard
                                                        // keyboard
            edittext.onTouchEvent(event); // Call native handler
            edittext.setInputType(inType); // Restore input type
            return true; // Consume touch event
        }
    });
    // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
    edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType()
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    edittext.setLongClickable(false);
    edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
}

}
```

When keyboard will appear I am animating the view which contain EditText so I think probably because of animation I am getting this problem.

*This is my animation code*

```
private void moveViewToScreenTop(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
            -(FontStyle.wheelViewTranslation));
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Could you please any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your layout xml have you assigned an id for that `EditText`? If yes you have not referenced any layout `EditText` in your activity.Your `EditText` should be instantiated something like ` EditText edittext = (EditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.resid);` where `resid` is the id of your `EditText` in your layout xml.

Comment: Yes, I assigned id for edit text and also registered same id with CustomKeyboard also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its not the best way to do it but should solve the problem

```
else if (primaryCode == CodeClear) {
        if (editable != null){
            editable.clear();
            edittext.setText("");
        }
```